# How do I put a command line interface inside a .net forms app?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, command-line-interface

I've been working on a project for a while that needs a command line in a panel.
The user needs to be able to read it and execute commands to it.

I've got some solutions that sort of work like running a seperate thread then running a command process. I can then read what the command line says in the console however I can not work out how to execute commands to it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MinecraftServerTool
{
    public partial class Home : Form
    {
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread th = new Thread(JavaRun);
            th.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            this.ConsolePanel.Controls.Add(this.ServerConsole);
        }

private void JavaRun()
        {
            Process ps = new Process();
            ps.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            ps.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            ps.Start();
            ps.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
            id = ps.Id;

            this.ServerConsole = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.ServerConsole.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight;
            this.ServerConsole.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            this.ServerConsole.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.ServerConsole.ItemHeight = 16;
            this.ServerConsole.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 265);
            this.ServerConsole.Name = "Console";
            this.ServerConsole.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 84);
            this.ServerConsole.TabIndex = 17;
            CmdOpen = true;

            while (CmdOpen == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ps.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
                if (ps.HasExited == true)
                {
                    CmdOpen = false;                    
                }
            }
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to replicate this then, the code above goes in the main (formname).cs file of a standard windows forms c# .net app. At the moment it should just create a list box, open a new command prompt and put the output of that command prompt in the console. Unfortunately the output will be in the apps console, not in the listbox I created (unfortunately).

My question is, should I continue creating a new thread that runs a command promt and write the output, or is there a way I can acutally fully integrate a command promt into a panel with like a NuGet package or something? Also can I have a global variable that both threads can access?

Sorry this question is quite weirdly written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Process.OutputDataReceived` is key to redirect output.

```
public partial class Home : Form
{
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        JavaRun();
    }

    private void JavaRun()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Process ps = new Process();
            ps.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
            {
                WorkingDirectory = @"C:\src",
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            };
            //Here is button click event, but you can give any event that you want to trigger command
            this.btnGo.Click += (s, e) => ps.StandardInput.WriteLine(this.txtCommand.Text); //output your command to process.
            this.btnExit.Click += (s, e) => ps.Kill();


            ps.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Log(e.Data);
            ps.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Log(e.Data);
            ps.Start();
            ps.BeginErrorReadLine();
            ps.BeginOutputReadLine();
            ps.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
            ps.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd..");
            ps.WaitForExit();
        });
    }

    private void Log(string value)
    {
        if (ServerConsole.IsDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (ServerConsole.InvokeRequired)
        {
            //allow thread to update main frame.
            ServerConsole.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ServerConsole.Items.Add(value);
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            ServerConsole.Items.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

BTW, Regarding to your first question about `Thread`, which is necessary to avoid blocking main frame, here I use `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead to shorten code, but it is not the reason of redirecting output.

Comment: Thankyou. How would I write a line to the process from a textbox when the user presses the button. I have the input from the textbox but I'm just slightly confused about how I put the variable in from outside.

Comment: @Leo updated my answer. it's a draft, you have to detail it on your own design.

Comment: Tysm I've been struggling with that for like 2 months :)

Comment: @Leo enjoy it. now you can select it as the answer.